# Block version 0x20000000

Tags: bitcoin-core, getblocktemplate, bip9-version-bits

When i run `getblocktemplate`, Bitcoind gives me in the `version` field a decimal number, when i convert it to `Hex` it's `20000000`

I know it must be in little endian, but to build the `blockheader` must i put it like this `00000020` or `02000000`  ?

I am asking this question because in version 1 the blockheaders are using `01000000` and not `00000010` so i am confused

Help is appreciated

Thanks to all of you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bytes you would put in the block header would be, in order: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x20. That's how the number *2<sup>21</sup>* (= 0x20000000) is stored in 32-bit little endian encoding.

Note that this is actually a large number; that range is used for [BIP9](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0009.mediawiki)-compatible versions. Older blocks that use versions 1 through 4 predate BIP9.